# How to return response from external function NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am new in `NodeJs` I am trying to get response from another function in Node Js.
I am calling slug function in `Nodejs`. I have to get the slug before insert but always I geting response `undefined` 
I am used noejs package slugs

```
var slugs = require("slugs");
```

I am calling 
`genslug(user.name)` like this way .

```
genslug(connection,slugs(user.name),1,slugs(user.name),callback)
```

Created one function `genslug` like this

```
var genslug = function(connection,slug,counter=1,orgSlug,callback) {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE slug = ?',slug,function(err,res) {
        if(err)
            callback({status: 'error', error : err});
        if(res.length > 0){
            counter++;
            slug = orgSlug+'-'+counter;
            genslug(connection,slug,counter,orgSlug,callback);
        }else{
            callback(false, slug);
        }
    });
}
```

But always I got `undefined`. 
Please response If anyone know this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Can you show your `slug` function from  where you are calling?

Comment: slug            : sluggen(connection,slugs(user.name),1,slugs(user.name),callback)

Answer (score 0):

Understand the callback nature.

First argument always takes as `error` and second takes as `success`.

In your case it always execute in error block from were you are calling the function since you are passing `else` in final callback.

> Try to remove `false` from final callback

```
var genslug = function(connection,slug,counter=1,orgSlug,callback) {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE slug = ?',slug,function(err,res) {
        if(err)
            callback({status: 'error', error : err});
        if(res.length > 0){
            counter++;
            slug = orgSlug+'-'+counter;
            genslug(connection,slug,counter,orgSlug);
        }else{
            callback(null, slug);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: always getting undefined.

Comment: how are you calling the `genslug` method? please update in question, your way of calling method is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

```
genslug(connection,slugs(user.name),1,slugs(user.name),function(err,resp){
   if(err)
   {
     console.log(err);
   }
   console.log(resp);
})

function genslug(connection,slug,counter=1,orgSlug,callback) {
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE slug = ?',slug,function(err,res) {
        if(err)
            callback(err,null);
        if(res.length > 0){
            counter++;
            slug = orgSlug+'-'+counter;
            //genslug(connection,slug,counter,orgSlug); - Callback function can't be call like this
        }else{
            callback(null, slug);
        }
    });
}
```